# Git merge conflict prevent deletes from newbs

Tags: git, file, merge, conflict

I have been searching for help on this for a while but I feel like the answer I always hear keep putting the blame on the users. This problem almost feels like a bug with git itself. Why does git even allow this situation occur?

Here is the situation. During a merge conflict, files that are not in conflict correctly end up in the staging area. Files that are in conflict must be dealt with.

I have some developers who just aren't familiar enough with git to realize that they should only be dealing with the conflicts and not the other files that are in the staging area. The newbie git user thought process goes something like this.

"I don't recognize those files, those aren't my files, I'm going to remove these from the staging area and only commit the files that I know are mine."

The result is that this newbie has just deleted a bunch of files from source control.

Aside from training, which we do plenty of, is there a git hook or some other strategy that I can employ to prevent this scenario. Unfortunately there is no merge-conflict hook, if there was then I could create a script and distribute that would gently remind the users not remove files from the staging area.

Pull requests you might say. Surely a pull request to a experienced dev would catch these kinds of problems. Well we use bitbucket server and for some reason the pull request preview doesn't show all the files that would be deleted in this scenario. It has something to do how complicated creating a merge preview actually is.

The result is that a bad merge conflict resolution removes a bunch of other peoples work from master. We find out about it hours or days later. We revert, we berate the offending dev and pray it never happens again but there has got to be a better way.

Any advice on this type of problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Education" and "don't let beginners do merges" (i.e., use pull requests instead) are the two main vectors here, but you've already tried them. I personally dislike much of both GitHub and Bitbucket pull request "added value" bits, because they try to hide a lot of complexity, without really getting *rid* of the complexity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a local git hook to check that the number of files in the working set during a merge commit with conflicts is about the number you expect (within some margin of error).

Here is an example of a pre-commit hook that will check that the number of files in the working set is within a certain percentage of the files that were changed by the branch being merged in.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -e ./.git/MERGE_HEAD ]
then
  echo This is a merge commit with conflicts. Checking to make sure the working set matches the merge diff.

  # This is the commit we are merging into our branch (probably master or origin/master)
  mergehead=$(cat .git/MERGE_HEAD)

  # This is the last commit on our branch
  orighead=$(cat .git/ORIG_HEAD)

  # This is the common ancestor to the merge head and orig head
  mergebase=$(git merge-base $mergehead $orighead)

  # Find all the changes between the common ancestor and the merge head
  linecountmerge=$(git diff-tree $mergebase $mergehead -r --name-only | wc -l)

  # Find all files in the working set and staging area but exclude untracked files
  # Remove files that start with a ' ' character as that represents unstaged files
  # Split Renamed files into 2 lines since diff-tree stores these separately as an Add and Delete
  linecountworking=$(git status -s -uno | egrep '^[^ ].*$' | sed 's/ -> /\r\n/g'  | wc -l)

  #Uncomment the following lines to produce these results to files for troubleshooting
  #git diff-tree $mergebase $mergehead -r --name-status | sort > .git/mergediff.txt
  #git status -s -uno | egrep '^[^ ].*$' | sed 's/^R/D/g;s/ -> /\r\nA  /g;s/\"//g;s/  /\t/g' | sort > .git/workingset.txt

  echo Found $linecountmerge files in the merge diff.
  echo Found $linecountworking files in the working set.

  percentage=$(($linecountworking*100/$linecountmerge))

  minimumallowedpercentage=60

  echo Working set file count is $percentage% of the merge diff file count.

  if [ $percentage -lt $minimumallowedpercentage ]
  then
    echo
    echo
    echo !!! Working set file count is less than $minimumallowedpercentage% of the merge diff file count. !!!
    echo This probably means that you removed files from the working set during a merge conflict, which is a BAD THING!
    echo If you are SURE you still want to commit the changes, you will need to add --no-verify to the commit command.
    echo
    echo Merge commit aborted.
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

This method will require you to get all your developers to install this hook on their local repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem is definitely a git flow issue.

What I like to do is something related to `git workflow` process (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), basically a feature branch is never merged/rebased once it has been created UNLESS explicitly told to do so by a git admin - most of the time because some structural changes have been made in the main branch.

Imagine a team of 10+ devs, and everyone working on a specific task. If everyone merges the main branch into the feature everytime, you will face the issue you are describing, incapacity of resolving merge conflicts.

The concept of the git workflow, is that you have some main developers that know about what everyone is working on, and that will make the feature branch merges into the main branch at the end of each sprint. Most of the time, they will be able to handle the conflicts, and if they can't, they can contact the devs responsible of the code and check with them.